# Restful service with CXF and Kerberos authentication

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs, cxf, kerberos

Having a hard time trying to protect an existing CXF JAX-RS service with Kerberos authentication.

I went through what seems to be the reference documentation : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-kerberos.html but it did not help much.

I'm actually trying to configure Tomcat+CXF to reproduce this kind of Apache configuration (which works) :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
AuthType Kerberos
KrbServiceName HTTP/fqdn@realm
Krb5Keytab /path/to/file.keytab
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

**jaas.conf** and **krb5.conf** were configured. The **KerberosAuthenticationFilter** was declared and referenced in CXF configuration as well. But I could not even reach the point where I get a 401 Forbidden status code.

I am stuck. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If I get bored somewhere this year, it might be likely that I will create a proper implemention here. It is unlikely that someone will give you a working solution/answer.

Comment: @Michael-O, Could you add the sample project for this, It would be Great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a solution.

CXF provides KerberosAuthenticationFilter but please **do not use CXF 3.0.1**. There was a bug raising a NullPointerException. It was fixed in a following version (I could not tell which one). Switching to CXF 3.0.8 fixed the issue.

1) You need to declare this filter in your beans.xml :

```
<bean id="kerberosFilter" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.security.KerberosAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="loginContextName" value="mycontext"/>
    <property name="servicePrincipalName" value="HTTP/serviceprincipal@MYDOMAIN.COM"/>
</bean>
```

2) and add a reference in your endpoint definition (still in beans.xml) :

```
<jaxrs:server address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="bean1" />
        <ref bean="bean2" />
        <ref bean="bean3" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="someProvider" />
        <ref bean="someExceptionMappper" />
        <ref bean="kerberosFilter" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

3) Add JAAS configuration file jaas.conf in Tomcat configuration path ($CATALINA_HOME/conf/) :

```
mycontext {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=true
    principal="HTTP/serviceprincipal@MYDOMAIN.COM"
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="/path/to/keytab/HTTP-serviceprincipal.keytab"
    debug=true
    storeKey=true;
};
```

4) Install krb5-user and curl to test :

```
$ kinit (to authenticate againt the KDC)
$ klist (to verify)
$ curl --negotiate -u : http://serviceprincipal/rest/someservice
```

Here the client (curl) will send a request to our protected server. The server will send back a 401 Unauthorized Status response containing a specific header : WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate.
Then the client will send the request again but this time it contains a token in its header metadata. Now the response should be as expected.

This works for me. I hope it helps someone else.

Ramzi

Answer (score 2):

You have to think about this:

1. Use [this](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/) this authenticator. Preferably from trunk or for Apache Web Server [this](https://github.com/michael-o/mod_spnego).
2. If CXF uses Apache HTTP Client, forget it. The current code is terrible. See [HTTPCLIENT-1625](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1625).

Comment: Thank you Michael but it says : "This works with Apache Tomcat 6.0 only due to ABI changes in version 7.0". We are currently using Tomcat 8.

Comment: @RamziOueslati, I am preparing version 2.0 right now. After that, I'd like to port it to Tomcat 8. There won't be any big difference in the code itself but on the in the Tomcat interfaces. Checkout from Subversion, swap Tomcat dependencies for 8.0 and fix interface compilation errors. This should do.

Comment: @Michael-O that looks great. Do you know if your sample-webapp would be runnable on Tomcat 8 as it is?

Comment: @JohannesJander, as long as you adapt the interface to Tocmat 8, It should be a no-brainer. The site contains various documentation on the topic sample webapp. Btw, you are only 3 km away from me.

Comment: @Michael-O Thanks, I'll give it a try next week.

Comment: @JohannesJander, just ping me if you like. I'd be glad to hear your success story. Make sure to use the code from trunk.

Comment: @Michael-O Thank you. I'll have a look at it then.