# How to implement Kerberos authentication (username and password required) to a java based REST service in a Windows 7 Enterprise PC?

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, kerberos

I have developed a REST web service using JAX-RS, hosted on Apache Tomcat server. I used Eclipse for developing this and hosted on a Windows 7 Enterprise machine. Now I need to provide Kerberos Authentication to access my service from any client (for example SoapUI). I have tried to get information from many sites but, all I get is configurations on linux machines. 
I'm a newbie to the security concepts and authentication mechanisms and architectures, I would appreciate a good detailed explanation.

Comment: What is your Tomcat version?

Comment: @Michael-O It is Tomcat 7

Comment: You might want to read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35349060/696632).

Comment: @Michael-O I'm clear with concept but, I'm confused on implementation, I need to know from scratch

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel where others already acomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good description of how to integrate Tomcat with Windows authentication:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html

Please note that there might be 2 separate things you might want, I'm not sure which one you are looking for.

1. Authenticate transparently with the Kerberos tickets the user already has.
2. Authenticate with username+password always, using MS AD to check them.

The first is always transparent, meaning the user does not have to enter username+password again. In the second one she obviously has to.

If you are looking for other services (like SoapUI) to access your services with Kerberos tickets, then those services would need to get a ticket themselves. If you just want those services to use username+password (instead of Kerberos), then you don't need a ticket of course.

**Edit after clarification**: Using username+password from a windows domain actually does not involve Kerberos at all. It is using LDAP to authenticate, which maps to JNDI in Java. There is a JNDIRealm in Tomcat to set it up, described here:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm

Comment: Thanks Robert, I need in the second case, user need to provide username + password always for authentication.

Comment: Then, what you are looking for is the JNDIRealm, documentation here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm. You are actually authenticating against LDAP, there is no Kerberos involved at all.

Comment: @ Robert Bräutigam Please have a look at the below link [https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/spnego/kerberos-authentication.html](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/spnego/kerberos-authentication.html). Here SoapUI need to be configured with SPNEGO/Kerberos. I need to develop a REST service which is authenticated like that shown in the article. I am a newbie and its bit complicated for me to understand

Comment: That is *not* username + password authentication, but the actual Kerberos one. For that you need the first link that I posted.

Comment: @ Robert Bräutigam but please refer to the screenshot here [link](https://www.soapui.org/soapui/media/images/stories/soap_and_wsdl/AuthHeader_new.png), here username + password is provided for authentication, please correct me If I misunderstood.

Comment: I did not yet use SoapUI to do SPNEGO authentication, I don't know the specifics to that. From the documentation it is not clear what it does. However SPNEGO will **not** send username + password to the server, so it is probably something soapui specific. It may use it for fallback for example, I don't really know.

Comment: @ Robert Bräutigam the link you have provided first is having some assumptions, I need to know How to do kerberos authentication from scratch. I'm confused whether any configuration need to be done on Windows PC or configuring Tomcat will suffice.